# How can I embed imagesin email that works on majority mail providers?

Tags: html, email, outlook

I know that this has been asked. I have read various articles on SO. But never understood them.

I have tried the following approaches.

HTML CODE:

```
    <html>
        <img class="center" style="" align="center" border="0" src="header.jpeg" alt="Image" title="Image" width="700">
        <span> Please find the enclosed report </span>
    </html>
```

Now, I want to embed my image in this e-mail and send it.

What I tried:

1) Base64 URI (For the header)

```
<img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAESAAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X...more encoding" />
```

**But that does not read on outlook.**

2) Attaching image as attachment (to header) and sending out the body html (Obviously, this doesn't work)

I have seen many websites doing it and they successfully send out proper email. How do they do that? What am I missing? **(I also noticed that they don't have any attachments attached. If it's not DataURI how do they do that?)**

- R

Answer (score 0):

Emails are a faff. it's all about old school HTML with inline CSS. Ditch the base URL and put the full URL path in the IMG tag like

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/2000px-Example.svg.png" alt="Smiley face" >
```

Comment: What if I don't want to link? I want to send image as well with the e-mail. How would I handle that? (Let's assume that I don't want to link and handle the traffic business)

Comment: I see, but you noted not wanting it as an attachment? The image has to come from somewhere :P Have you thought about using a contend delivery network like Amazon CloudFront to host the image? (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not support embedded (`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64...>`) images - Word does not render them.

Embedding images through the content id (`<img src="cid:xyz">` where xyz is the value of the Cintent-ID attribute on the image attachment MIME part) works in all email clients.

Referring to the images by their url does not work too well in Outlook - it blocks all external content by default unless the user clicks on a button on each email.